# Is there any substitute for Postgres ALL Operator?

Tags: postgresql, jsqlparser

I'm trying to execute this:

```
SELECT id, title FROM book 
    WHERE author_id != all('{
        {d778ee4f-e7cf-436e-8975-8f6ca2cccb2a},
        {17db25c6-0d61-4f23-826e-4f2982bcc490}
    }'::uuid[]);
```

This select SQL works perfectly in Postgres but, the main problem is because I'm using JsqlParser to parse this statement, at this moment `!= all` an error is thrown. How can I change just this code snippet here `! = All` and get the same result?

Edit1: I tried not in:

```
SELECT id, title from book 
    WHERE author_id NOT IN ('{
        {d778ee4f-e7cf-436e-8975-8f6ca2cccb2a},
        {17db25c6-0d61-4f23-826e-4f2982bcc490}
    }'::uuid[]);

SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: operator does not exist: uuid <> uuid[]
```

Edit2: I tried `<>` to

```
SELECT id, title from book 
    WHERE author_id <> ('{
        {d778ee4f-e7cf-436e-8975-8f6ca2cccb2a},
        {17db25c6-0d61-4f23-826e-4f2982bcc490}
    }'::uuid[]);

SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: operator does not exist: uuid <> uuid[]
```

Obs. I already opened an issue here: [JsqlParser repository](https://github.com/JSQLParser/JSqlParser/issues/1140)

Comment: Have you tried using `not in` ?

Comment: Did you try the standard not equals operator `<>`

Comment: If the problem is with JsqlParser, you should tag it.

Comment: if the filter inside where is just going to be two values why not just go with AND ?

Comment: must you use arrays? I suspect it is the use of arrays that is leading to the issue as indicated by `uuid <> uuid[]` only one side of that refers to an array

Comment: There are no limits in arrays, I used two as an example.